# Some services are not able to be constructed (Error while validating the service descriptor) C#

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, dependency-injection, .net-5

I am making asp .NET core web API and I made some services and I injected it and it is working fine.
I made a new web app in the same solution and I want to use the same services
and I just got

> Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceProvider..ctor(IEnumerable serviceDescriptors, IServiceProviderEngine engine, ServiceProviderOptions options)

> AggregateException: Some services are not able to be constructed (Error while validating the service descriptor 'ServiceType: E_CommerceApi.Services.IAttributeService Lifetime: Scoped ImplementationType: E_CommerceApi.Services.AttributeService': Unable to resolve service for type 'E_CommerceApi.Authentication.ApplicationDbContext' while attempting to activate 'E_CommerceApi.Services.AttributeService'.)

Service and IService Code

```
 public interface IAttributeService
 {
   Task<AllAttributes> GetAll();
 }


 public class AttributeService : IAttributeService
 {
   private readonly ApplicationDbContext _db;
   public AttributeService(ApplicationDbContext db)
   {
       _db = db;
   }
 }
```

Injecting the service in the same project

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddControllers();
    services.AddDbContext<ApplicationDbContext>(options => options.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("ConnStr")));
    // register services
    services.AddScoped<IAttributeService, AttributeService>();
}
```

Injecting service in another web project which is not working

```
  public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
  {
      services.AddControllersWithViews();
      services.AddScoped<IAttributeService, AttributeService>();
  }
```

Comment: The second project seems to be missing a call to `AddDbContext<ApplicationDbContext>`.

Comment: you mean to add and install  entity framework in every project I want to use this service?

Comment: How do you expect `AttributeService` to be constructed when you aren't registering the `ApplicationDbContext` it depends on?

Comment: @esamaldinelzain: Not in every project, but at least in every [Composition Root](https://freecontent.manning.com/dependency-injection-in-net-2nd-edition-understanding-the-composition-root/) (i.e. every startup project).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As you are not registering the DBContext in your second project,

```
services.AddDbContext<ApplicationDbContext>(options => options.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("ConnStr")));
```

the attempt to resolve the `IAttributeService` fails because its implementation (`AttributeService`) expects it to be injected into its constructor.

However, if I understand what you're trying to do, and I'm not sure I do, it seems you want to be able to access the services in your second project without having to do this.

Is your second project a completely separate web application?

If so then you need to register all of the components it needs. So add the DBContext.

If not, ie. if it is a referenced project with controllers and views that are to be included in the main project via its reference. Then you need to consider this as a module of your main web hosted application. You would not then have another Startup class and you would not need to register any services. Instead you would be able to access any services via the first container and their interface.

If the second project has services that need to be registered into the container then you would need some way of doing this, such as an extension method on the `IServiceCollection` so it can be called in the main ConfigureServices method.

```
public static void RegisterSecondProjectModule(this IServiceCollection services)
{
    // register your services here
    services.AddScoped...
}

// then in your main ConfigureServices method:
services.RegisterSecondProjectModule();
```

Note: For any services you want to be available across both / all projects in your solution, it would make sense to move the interface into a separate project that both can reference. I typically create a project with a name suffix of `.Abstractions` and change the default namespace to exclude it.